# Python 3.6 SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, mqtt

I'm using the following code to connect with labeeb-iot broker.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("/focus/temp/SEnsor1/Model1/Temperature/data")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  print(msg.payload.decode())

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.tls_set("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.connect("mea.labeeb-iot.com",8883,60)

client.loop_forever()
```

after the execution of the following code the result is :

[image]

Comment: I'm using Linux Manjaro (ArchLiux)

Comment: Please read the doc about asking good questions, as it stands this question should be closed as it is just a code listing and "this is broken" question, which is normally considered to be off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also as a rule MQTT topics should not start with a leading `/` as this just adds a null element to the start of the topic tree.

Comment: The issue was resolved and certificate has been activated some time after the question was posted. we just noticed this question , sorry for delay. for any help or support you can contact us on : support@labeeb-iot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate on the broker expired on the 26th May this year.

You can verify this with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -verify 2  -connect mea.labeeb-iot.com:8883 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Which will print something like:

> depth=0 C = QA, ST = Qatar, L = Doha, O = Qatar Mobility Innovations
>   Center (QMIC), CN = *.labeeb-iot.com notAfter=May 26 12:24:38 2017 GMT
>   verify return:1

Comment: Who ever owns the broker needs to get a new certificate

Comment: A very unsafe approach would be to see what tls_insecure_set(True) does.

Comment: Given this looks to be a broker connected to the internet with what looks to be no authentication, I suppose it can't get much worse by passing the SSL verification.